unable to render jinja template properly
I have issue with jinja template rendering, I have my jinja template something like this
I am trying to render virtual service yaml , but I am unable to render
serviceRoutes:
  gateways:
    {% for gateway in gateways %}
    - {{ gateway }}
    {% endfor %}
  hosts:
    {% for host in hosts %}
    - {{ host }}
    {% endfor %}
  http:
    {% for item in http %}
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: {{ item.match.prefix }}
      {% if item.get('rewrite') %}
      rewrite:
        uri: {{ item.rewrite.uri }}
      {% endif %}
      route: 
        - destination:
            host: "{{ item['destination']['host'] }}"
            port:
              number: {{ item['destination']['port']['number'] }}
          weight: {{ item['weight'] }}
    {% endfor %}

and I have my value file .
serviceRoutes:
- sr: 
  name: sr1
  gateways:
    - mesh
    - "test.usnabk.com"
  hosts:
    - "1.one.bank-dns.com"
    - "tes.one.bank-dns.com"
  http:
      - match:
          prefix: "base_path"
        route: 
          - destination:
              host: "one.bank-dns.com"
              port:
                number: 8080
            weight: 100
      - match:
          prefix: "base_path"
        rewrite:
          uri: "base_path"
        route: 
          - destination:
              host: "one.bank-dns.com"
              port:
                number: 8080
            weight: 100

my python script is
`
import yaml
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Load values from YAML file
    with open('./test.yaml', 'r') as f:
        values = yaml.safe_load(f)

    # Load Jinja environment
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('./template'), trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True)
    template = env.get_template('template.j2')

    # Iterate over each service route
    for service in values["serviceRoutes"]:
        # Render the template for each service route
        rendered = template.render(service)
        
        # Write the rendered content to a YAML file
        with open("abc.yaml", "w") as output_file:
            output_file.write(rendered)`

I am unable to render route block.
My expectation is to render temlate , but I am getting this is error
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'destination'


In your data your destination is under serviceRoutes[].http[].route[].destination and you are trying to look for it under serviceRoutes[].http[].destination, you are obviously missing a for somewhere to iterate the items of route, e.g. for route in http.route.
